# Boxed pancake mix - Allpurpose or Cake Flour?

Tags: cake

Is boxed pancake mix usually made out of Allpurpose flour, or cake flour?

Comment: All purpose and cake flour are standard categories for labeling flour at retail (at least in the US).

At the scale cake mixes are produced they are not buying flour at retail; their flour is probably a proprietary blend created to their specifications.  

It is likely to be closer to typical cake flour in grind size and protein level.

Comment: You should post this as an answer :-) Also don't forget about adding few links that explains the "all purpose" or "cake flour" as a standard jargon. I dare say that "all purpose" is used worldwide and in the UK and OZ we call it"wheat fflour"

Answer (score 2):

Most pancake recipes call for all purpopse flour.  I assume boxed mixes do the same, or a mix of all purpose and cake flour for a lighter texture.

The difference between them is 'hard' and 'soft' flours.  Hard flours (AP, Bread, semolina, etc.) have more gluten/protein in them, which contributes a chewier texture. Soft flours such as cake are a finer grind and give cakes a crumblier (word?) and lighter texture.  If you used AP for an angel food cake, it would be dense and chewy, rather than light and airy.

AP is generally a mix of hard and soft flours, and can be used for many cakes, breads, and of course pancakes.  Since pancakes tend to have a chewier texture than many baked goods, they probably use an AP-type flour.

Since pancakes are reletively cheap to make, experiment with it. Try bread, AP, cake, and varioius combinations.  There is a recipe in Mark Bittman's *How to Cook Everything* where you separate the eggs, whip the whites into a foam, and fold it into the batter before cooking.  I imagine this would go well with cake flour.

[Wheat Flour (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_flour)